# Error al conectar con base de datos MYSQL con java

Tags: java, mysql

estoy haciendo un programa en java y necesito hacer una conexión a la BDD en MySQL, en principio todo funciona correctamente y cuando le doy a ejecutar me sale un mensaje de que la conexión es correcta, pero en la clase de CONEXION2 me sale un mensaje justo debajo que dice: **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "cn" is null
at conexion.Conexion2.main(Conexion2.java:23)
** (he puesto comentado dónde es el error). Llevo un rato dándole vueltas y no entiendo por qué "cn" lo reconoce como null. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/videojuegos";
    private static final String user = "root";
    private static final String pass = "andres";
    
    static { //Así no llamamos al controlador una y otra vez. Es más eficiente.
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Error al cargar controlador.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public Connection conectar () {
        
        Connection conexion = null;
        try {
            
            DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            
            System.out.println("Conexión correcta");
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            System.out.println("Error de conexión");
        }
        return conexion;
        
    }
  
    


}
```

````
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Conexion2 {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion(); //Este objeto tiene la referencia entre la conexion de al aplicacion y la BDD
        
        Connection cn = null;
        Statement stm = null; //creamos sentencia SQL
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        try {
            cn = conexion.conectar(); 

            stm = cn.createStatement(); //<---ERROR AQUÍ
            rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM videogames"); 
            
            //recorrer tabla juegos
            while (rs.next()) {
                
                int idJuego = rs.getInt(1); //columna 1
                String nombrejuego = rs.getString(2);
                
                System.out.println(idJuego + "-" + nombrejuego);
                
                
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally { //Para liberar recursos. Opcional.
            try {
                if(rs!= null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                
                if(stm!= null) {
                    stm.close();
                }
                
                if(cn!= null) {
                    cn.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no estás asignando la conexión en ningún momento.

Prueba así:

```
public Connection conectar () {
    
    try 
    {
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Conexión correcta");
        return conexion;
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        
        System.out.println("Error de conexión");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias, funciona perfectamente.

Comment: @AndresGards me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.